# Is it OK to ignore DbUpdateConcurrencyException?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency

I have a table that effectively implements a cache - we put stuff in, we take stuff out. It has a last_accessed field that indicates when it was inserted or read, and it has a max_age field indicating how long to keep the record.

We want to purge old records, rather than having them accumulate.  Seemed to me that the easiest way to handle that was just to call a purge routine, every time we accessed a record.

This is simple enough to do, in EF:

```
var oldCacheItems =
    this.xxDbContext.XXtokencaches.Where(
        t => EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(t.lastAccessed, t.expirationMinutes) < DateTime.Now);

    this.xxDbContext.XXtokencaches.RemoveRange(oldCacheItems);
    this.xxDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Works fine, alone. But when I have multiple clients running, I occasionally get DbUpdateConcurrencyExceptions:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2146233087 
Message=Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
Source=EntityFramework
```

Browsing around, I see a lot of discussion about concurrency issues in EF. But in this case, I'm not sure any of it matters.  In essence, this particular error is EF complaining that it can't delete the records because someone else already deleted them.

So I'm considering simply catching DbUpdateConcurrencyException and ignoring it.

Are there any possible consequences to this that I might not have considered?

Or some alternative approach that would eliminate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your business logic. You can assume that database version wins over yours.